# When was the FIDE title of Candidate Master first awarded?

Tags: fide, titles

Specifically, in which FIDE rating list do players first appear with the Candidate Master title?

And which country (federation) had all the titles in that first list? Not that I'm suggesting a stitch up :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a quiz question, you probably know the answer but anyway ...

The first rating list that contains the Candidate Master title is April 2002 and all the players on that list with the said title are from England followed by Wales in the next rating list (July 2002). There are two relatively well known names among the first eleven people in history who held the CM title.

Comment: Indeed. It was Stewart Reuben CM (ENG) who introduced the title - https://www.ecforum.org.uk/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1077&p=16752#p16776 .

Comment: do you know the answer for FIDE master? https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36898/list-of-records-for-the-youngest-fide-masters-since-1950