# List of records for the youngest FIDE masters since 1950?

Tags: history, statistics, records, titles

**Edit** based on answer given by blunderchess1236 awhile ago: I'm not looking for just 1 person like who most recently attained the youngest (Alekhine Nouri). I'm asking also who held the record for youngest before Alekhine Nouri and who held the record before that person and so on until the 1st FM/s. (or alternatively start with the 1st FM/s

---

On Wiki, we have the [List of youngest grandmasters since 1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_prodigy#List_of_youngest_grandmasters). What about the list but for FMs (FIDE masters) instead of GMs? How might I go about obtaining this list?

**Way 1 - start from most recent**: It appears Philippine player [Alekhine Nouri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alekhine_Nouri) is on this list. [Here](https://www.philstar.com/sports/2013/06/18/955273/phl-chess-whiz-kid-7-youngest-fide-master)'s a source, but it doesn't say who the previous youngest was. If I knew who was the youngest before Nouri, then I  could search the 1 before that 1 and so on.

**Way 2 - start from the 1st FM/s**: Who was/were the 1st FM/s? When I look this up, I mostly find just the 1st FMs of certain countries. eg Gerald Mphungu - malawi, Ricko Depaune - Nauru, Peter Wong - Australia but for composition. It seems so weird that this information isn't readily available. It seems to be the case as well for candidate masters: [When was the FIDE title of Candidate Master first awarded?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21522/when-was-the-fide-title-of-candidate-master-first-awarded)

**Note 1**: It appears [Susan Polgar](https://www.lubbockonline.com/article/20110603/OPINION/306039887) may be on this list at the age of 12 or 13.

**Update 2**: [It seems](https://www.chessgames.com/player/etienne_bacrot.html?kpage=1) Étienne Bacrot (who holds a youngest GM record) is on the list for youngest FM records.

Answer (score 1):

"From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Alekhine Nouri (born December 12, 2005) is a Filipino FIDE Master. Named after Russian chess player Alexander Alekhine, Nouri became the youngest Filipino FIDE Master and the youngest FIDE Master in the world at the age of 7."

It seems like this person is who you are looking for.

Comment: i already mentioned Alekhine Nouri. i want to know the full **list**. like who was the record holder before Alekhine Nouri. and the 1 before that and the 1 before that. all the way until the very 1st FM (or youngest among the 1st set of FMs in case the FM title was given to more than 1 person the 1st time around)

Comment: Etienne Bacrot achieved it at 10

Comment: blunderchess1236 ok thanks! [Bacrot was indeed youngest](https://www.chessgames.com/player/etienne_bacrot.html?kpage=1). edit that into your answer please.  question - was Bacrot's record the record just prior to nouri's?

Comment: @BCLC Hello. Bacrot was born in 1983 so he got it at 1993. Nouri got it at 2012.

Comment: how do you know there wasn't like a 9 year old FM? 8 year old?

Comment: Sorry for late replay. Got it from Wikipedia.

Comment: Search up all the grandmasters in the database and look up their FIDE rating. Then look at when their rating crosses 2300.

Comment: what database? why don't you edit these comments into answer?